# What is the standard CodeCacheManager JMX bean?

Tags: java, jmx

`CodeCacheManager` appears to be a standard JVM JMX bean, but I can't find any documentation on it anywhere.

What is it?  And does anyone have reference documentation for the other standard JMX beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JConsole documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

> Code Cache (non-heap): The HotSpot Java VM also includes a code cache,
>   containing memory that is used for compilation and storage of native
>   code.

JMX bean you have observed is related to monitoring this space.

Comment: You are near to Google (in proximity), still didn't show up? That is bad. Ha ha!

Comment: The management beans for the Java platform are documented in JavaDoc as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html